# Run while loop for multiple test cases where number of cases is not known

Tags: python-3.x

So I had recently taken part in a coding challenge in college. 
There in one of the questions, I had to run a loop for multiple test cases, the problem being that number of test cases is not specified.

Now I know I can implement this in c++ by

```
char x[100]; 
while(cin>>x)
{    
  // Code 
}
```

But I am unable to implement this in Python. How should I go about it?

The code I tried for python is :

```
a = input("")
while a:
   #code
   a=input("")
```

Now when I run it on IDE like Jupyter Notebook, we give inputs so this works. However when I run it in online IDE like Codechef or Hacker rank, I get an EOF error.

The inputs are basically strings and one of them is:

RA1700384648373
ra1784757789599.
Ra6477

Comment: The code simply runs without any error. Put a new line at the end of your code and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Your code returns an EOF(end of file) error in online python interpreters because the do not support normal interactive input.
example:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php

your code is correct